# Decipher .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to upgrade an old PHP script to version 5 - the server is running 5.4.17. Links that worked before are not working anymore and I suspect the server. To determine the servers' guilt in this matter I need to understand a .htaccess file. Can you tell me what this does?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^System/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It routes all requests for either something in the `System` folder or for a file that doesn't exist to the `index.php` and setting the `$_GET['_path']` variable to the request.

To check if this is the problem, try going to a URL like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?_path=something
```

where "something" is a page you used to be able to go to but is not working anymore.